# Cont Monad breaks laziness in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations

I was trying the Cont monad, and discovers the following problem.

1. First construct a infinite list and lift all the elements to a Cont monad
2. Use sequence operation to get a Cont monad on the infinite list.
3. When we try to run the monad, with head, for example, it falls into infinite loop
   while trying to expand the continuation and the head is never called.

The code looks like this:

```
let inff = map (return :: a -> Cont r a) [0..]
let seqf = sequence inff
runCont seqf head
```

So is this a limitation of the Cont monad implementation in Haskell?
If so, how do we improve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the Haskell sequence function can't be lazy or why recursive monadic functions can't be lazy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494648/why-the-haskell-sequence-function-cant-be-lazy-or-why-recursive-monadic-functio)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is that even though the *value* of the head element of `sequence someList` depends only on the first elemenent of `someList`, the *effect* of `sequence someList` can generally depend on all the effects of `someList` (and it does for most monads). Therefore, if we want to evaluate the head element, we still need to evaluate all the effects.

For example, if we have a list of `Maybe` values, the result of `sequence someList` is `Just` only if all the elements of `someList` are `Just`. So if we try to `sequence` an infinite list, we'd need to examine its infinite number of elements if they're all `Just`.

The same applies for `Cont`. 
In the continuation monad, we can escape any time from the computation and return a result that is different from what has been computed so far.
Consider the following example:

```
test :: (Num a, Enum a) => a
test = flip runCont head $
    callCC $ \esc -> do
        sequence (map return [0..100] ++ [esc [-1]])
```

or directly using `cont` instead of `callCC`:

```
test' :: (Num a, Enum a) => a
test' = flip runCont head $
            sequence (map return [0..100] ++ [cont (const (-1))])
```

The result of `test` is just `-1`. After processing the first 100 elements, the final element can decide to escape all of this and return `-1` instead. So in order to see what is the `head` element of `sequence someList` in `Cont`, we again need to compute them all.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a flaw with the `Cont` monad so much as `sequence`.  You can get similar results for `Either`, for example:

```
import Control.Monad.Instances ()

xs :: [Either a Int]
xs = map Right [0..]  -- Note: return = Right, for Either

ys :: Either a [Int]
ys = sequence xs
```

You can't retrieve any elements of `ys` until it computes the entire list, which will never happen.

Also, note that: `sequence (map f xs) = mapM f xs`, so we can simplify this example to:

```
>>> import Control.Monad.Instances
>>> mapM Right [0..]
<Hangs forever>
```

There are a few monads where `mapM` will work on an infinite list of values, specifically the lazy `StateT` monad and `Identity`, but they are the exception to the rule.

Generally, `mapM`/`sequence`/`replicateM` (without trailing underscores) are anti-patterns and the correct solution is to use `pipes`, which allows you to build effectful streams that don't try to compute all the results up front.  [The beginning of the `pipes` tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.0/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html) describes how to solve this in more detail, but the general rule of thumb is that any time you write something like:

```
example1 = mapM f xs

example2 = sequence xs
```

You can transform it into a lazy `Producer` by just transforming it to:

```
example1' = each xs >-> Pipes.Prelude.mapM f

example2' = each xs >-> Pipes.Prelude.sequence
```

Using the above example with `Either`, you would write:

```
>>> import Pipes
>>> let xs = each [0..] >-> mapM Right :: Producer Int (Either a) ()
```

Then you can lazily process the stream without generating all elements:

```
>>> Pipes.Prelude.any (> 10) xs
Right True
```

Comment: I think calling mapM an anti-pattern in general is a bit harsh. I'd say it's bad only if the list is of unbounded length (for example derived from user input). But there e.g. isn't much wrong with calling mapM on a list of at most 100 elements.

Comment: The mapM function is not an anti-pattern at all, not any more than effects being an anti-pattern.

Comment: Using something with O(N^2) space and time complexity that doesn't stream when a streaming O(N) solution exists is an anti-pattern in my eyes.  Also, note that the OP specifically describes this behavior as problematic in their own words, so this statement is relevant in the context of this question.

Comment: Thank you for the information about Pipes, looks great.