# Operating infinite lists with strict monads

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation, conduit, strictness

I have a function `f :: [a] -> b` that operates on infinite lists (e.g. `take 5`, `takeWhile (< 100) . scanl (+) 0` and so on). I want to feed this function with values generated by strict monadic actions (e.g. `randomIO`).

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494648/why-the-haskell-sequence-function-cant-be-lazy-or-why-recursive-monadic-functio), I've learned that the `repeat` and `sequence` trick approach does not work for strict monads, as the example below show:

```
import Control.Monad.Identity

take 5 <$> sequence (repeat $ return 1) :: Identity [Int]
-- returns `Identity [1,1,1,1,1]`
-- works because Identity is non-strict

take 5 <$> sequence (repeat $ return 1) :: IO [Int]
 -- returns `*** Exception: stack overflow`
 -- does not work because IO is strict
```

So, instead, I thought about using the function "inside" the monadic context. I was inspired by this [circular programming example](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-09-recursive-do.html) and tried:

```
let loop = do
       x <- return 1
       (_, xs) <- loop
       return (take 5 xs, x:xs)
in  fst loop :: Identity [Int]
-- Overflows the stack
```

and

```
import Control.Monad.Fix

fst <$> mfix (\(_, xs) -> do
   x <- return 1
   return (take 5 xs, x:xs)) :: Identity [Int]
-- Overflows the stack
```

and even

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}
import System.Random

loop' = mdo
   (xs', xs) <- loop xs
   return xs'
where loop xs = do
      x <- randomIO
      return (take 5 xs, x:xs)

print $ loop'
-- Returns a list of 5 identical values
```

But none of these works. I also tried a `Conduit` approach which did not work either even in the `Identity` case:

```
import Conduit

runConduitPure $ yieldMany [1..] .| sinkList >>= return . take 5
```

Therefore I would like to know:

1. Why none of the "circular" approaches above work?
2. If there exists a solution to this that does not involve `unsafeInterleaveIO`. (maybe `iteratee`s, `Arrow`s?)

Comment: In general, this is a tough problem. For random numbers in particular, there is an easy way out: `randoms <$> newStdGen :: Random a => IO [a]` is an infinite random list of whatever you want (that is `Random`).

Comment: @Alec Thanks for the comment. I am using `randomIO` here just for simplicity of the examples. In practice, I would like to process messages received via sockets.

Comment: So something like the infinite list of messages received from a socket?

Comment: @Alec Exactly. More specifically, instead of `randomIO`, I am using `receive sock` where `sock` is a ZeroMQ `Socket z` monad (see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/zeromq4-haskell-0.6.5/docs/System-ZMQ4-Monadic.html )

Comment: @DouglasVieira in the `conduit` program, shouldn't you be using `take` inside the conduit? `>>> runConduit $ sourceRandom .| takeC 5 .| sinkList :: IO [Bool]` gives me `[False,False,False,False,True]` Here `sourceRandom` is standing in for your stream of messages, but the pure case works as well. Really a list shouldn't be constructed, you should do whatever you were going to do with it inside the conduit.

Comment: I don't think lazyiness can explain this, by the way. `Maybe` is lazy, but `take 5 <$> sequence (repeat $ Just 1) :: Maybe [Int]` also hangs since if the zillionth element of the list were `Nothing`, it would return `Nothing`. Similarly `take 5 <$> sequence (repeat  [1]) :: [[Int]]` would be `[]` if somewhere in the list of lists there's an empty list.

Comment: @Michael Regarding your first comment, see my comment on @duplode's answer. Regarding your second comment, I do not see exactly the point. For the `Maybe` monad, I guess the problem is that only possible fixed point in the monadic context (between `Just a` or `Nothing`) is `Nothing`, so `sequence`ing an infinite list of `Just a`s will just hang forever. `Identity a` does not have this issue because the fixed point of the monadic context is already `Identity a` (the same intuitively would also apply for `IO a` if there were no side-effects).

Comment: My point was about strict v lazy. Identity is by the way maximally strict since it is a newtype. I think you just have to work through the definition of `sequence` i.e. `foldr (\m ms -> (:) <$> m <*> ms) (pure [])` together with the monad (applicative) implementation in each concrete case to see why in `Identity` things go so swimmingly and in `IO` (so often) badly.  It is basically to avoid `sequence` that we have the streaming libraries. From the point of view of the streaming libraries, `sequence`  `mapM` `replicateM` etc. for IO + lists are the fundamental red flags.

Comment: @Michael Now I see, good point! Some examples illustrates the strictness property that you mentioned: `seq (return undefined :: Identity ()) ()`, `seq (return undefined :: Maybe ()) ()`, `seq (return undefined :: IO ()) ()`. As you pointed out, the case with `Identity` throws an error, as it is defined as a newtype. Interestingly, the case with `IO` does not throw an error, although `print 1 >> return ()` does print `1` in the terminal. In [John L's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14496898/6537490), he mentions the strictness of `(>>=)`, which is the one that plays a role here.

Comment: With  `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy` if I write `a = take 5 <$> sequence (repeat $ return 1) :: StateT () Identity [Int]` I can write `>>> evalStateT a ()` and manage to get `Identity [1,1,1,1,1]` with `>>> runStateT a ()` I get `Identity ([1,1,1,1,1], ` and it pauses while it tries to get the () at the end of the rainbow - so there comes a stack overflow.  With `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict` both end up in a stack overflow. `sequence` is really pretty toxic for lists, though there are uses of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am using randomIO here just for simplicity of the examples. In practice, I would like to process messages received via sockets

*That* is not possible without `unsafeInterleaveIO`. The problem at the end of the day is that `IO` actions must be sequenced. While the order of evaluation for referentially transparent values doesn't matter, that of `IO` actions may. If you want a lazy infinite list of all the messages received over a socket, you have to inform Haskell a priori where in the sequence of `IO` actions this fits (unless you use `unsafeInterleaveIO`).

The `Arrow` abstraction you are seeking is called [`ArrowLoop`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowLoop), but it too has a problem with the *right tightening law* for strict monads.

At first sight, it may look like [`MonadFix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html) (manifested via `mdo` or `mfix`) is a solution too, but digging a bit deeper [shows that `fixIO` has problems](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#fixIO), just like `loop` from `ArrowLoop`.

However, sometimes the restriction that `IO` actions must be run one after another is a bit excessive and that is what `unsafeInterleaveIO` is for. Quoting the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeInterleaveIO)

> `unsafeInterleaveIO` allows `IO` computation to be deferred lazily. When passed a value of type `IO a`, the `IO` will only be performed when the value of the `a` is demanded.

---

Now, even if you explicitly said that you *didn't* want an `unsafeInterleaveIO` solution, as I have hopefully managed to convince you it is the way to go, here it is:

```
interweavingRepeatM :: IO a -> IO [a]
interweavingRepeatM action = unsafeInterleaveIO ((:) <$> action <*> interweavingRepeatM action)
```

And here is is working for random numbers:

```
ghci> import System.Random
ghci> sourceOfRandomness <- interweavingRepeatM randomIO :: IO [Integer]
ghci> take 10 sourceOfRandomness
[-2002742716261662204,7803971943047671004,-8395318556488893887,-7372674153585794391,5906750628663631621,6428130029392850107,6453903217221537923,-8966011929671667536,6419977320189968675,-1842456468700051776]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. Could you elaborate more on: 1. How to address this issue for a general monad transformed from `IO`? 2. Why the `mdo` approach gave repeated values?

Comment: @DouglasVieira 1. I don't think you can in general - monads are meant to encode that nature of sequencing 2. `mdo` desugars to use `fixIO` and `fixIO` confusingly only evaluates its action _once_ (looking at the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#fixIO) may be helpful). Even if you had managed to write something that really should have returned a list, you would have hit your head against an even more confusing `MVar` related error message (or worse yet - a hanging program).

Comment: @DouglasVieira With respect to 1. - I see that the package you linked also exposes `IO` functions. You could use those and `unsafeInterleaveIO` to get your list, then `liftIO` back into your desired monad.

Answer (score 3):

[Alec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42173117/2751851) covers your general question. What follows is specifically about *conduit* and similar streaming libraries.

> I also tried a `Conduit` approach which did not work either even in the `Identity` case:
>
> ```
> import Conduit
>
> runConduitPure $ yieldMany [1..] .| sinkList >>= return . take 5
> ```

While streaming libraries are commonly used to avoid the sort of difficulty you mention (cf. the opening remarks of [`Pipes.Tutorial`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.2/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html)), they assume you will use their stream types *instead of* lists. Consider, for instance, how [`sinkList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-combinators-1.1.0/docs/Conduit.html#v:sinkList) is described by the `Conduit` documentation:

> Consume all values from the stream and return as a list. Note that this will pull all values into memory.

That means using `sinkMany` immediately after `yieldMany` brings you back to square one: bringing all values into memory is precisely what makes the combination of `sequence`, `IO` and infinite lists unusable. What you should do instead is using the infrastructure of the streaming library to build the stages of your pipeline. Here are a few simple examples using mostly ready-made things from *conduit* and *conduit-combinators*:

```
GHCi> import Conduit
GHCi> runConduitPure $ yieldMany [1..] .| takeC 5 .| sinkList
[1,2,3,4,5]
GHCi> runConduit $ yieldMany [1..] .| takeC 5 .| printC -- try it without takeC
1
2
3
4
5
GHCi> runConduit $ yieldMany [1..] .| takeC 5 .| scanlC (+) 0 .| printC
0
1
3
6
10
15
GHCi> :{
GHCi| runConduit $ yieldMany [1..] .| takeC 5
GHCi|     .| awaitForever (\x -> liftIO (print (2*x)) >> yield x)
GHCi|     .| printC
GHCi| :}
2
1
4
2
6
3
8
4
10
5
GHCi> runConduit $ (sourceRandom :: Producer IO Int) .| takeC 5 .| printC 
1652736016140975126
5518223062916052424
-1236337270682979278
8079753510915129274
-609160753105692151
```

(Thanks [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183792/michael) for making me notice `sourceRandom` -- at first I had rolled my own with `repeatMC randomIO`.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding `Conduit`. The problem, however, is that is that I want a solution to work on an arbitrary function `f :: [a] -> b` that really operates on (infinite) lists. Therefore, as you pointed out, `Conduit` is not the solution I am looking for. Even worse, as pointed out by @Alec, there is no solution to the general case. To give more context, I was trying to work on a simple implementation of Functional Reactive Programming, where the primitive type `Event :: Ord t => [(t, a)]` is an infinite list ordered by time (i.e. I actually wanted `f :: Event -> b`).

Comment: The functions `f` that you actually mention - "(e.g. take 5, takeWhile (< 100) . scanl (+) 0 and so on)" - are elementary stream transformations that all really operate on infinite streams. You haven't given a reason why you are using infinite lists rather than streams, which support almost the whole api of `Data.List` without needing `sequence` and co. That sequence can't be salvaged 'in the general case' is the whole point.